# Why style.css with ?ver=3.9.2 not updating as the one without ?ver=3.9.2?

Tags: themes

The problem I have is the style.css I uploaded to the host server not taking affect.
I am using GoDaddy business wordpress hosting.

Please note the following two having different content, only the first one applied my updates:
http://auapg.com/wp-content/themes/homeland/style.css
http://auapg.com/wp-content/themes/homeland/style.css?ver=3.9.2

I am not sure what magic the '?ver=3.9.2' did to the css file. 
Anyway I am hoping it can have the same content as the one without '?ver=3.9.2', which applied my changes.
Any ideas is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: stylesheet url without version is already cached and you are being viewed a chached version. But when you pass a query string, browser ask server for updated version. It's pretty standard.

Comment: @Roberthue Thanks for the information. The one with version supposed to be updated is actually not getting updated, but the cached one got updated, that's ironic :D

Comment: I solved the problem by reading this page: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-rid-of-ver-on-the-end-of-cssjs-files

Answer (score 1):

The `?ver=3.9.2` or similar part of enqueued styles (and scripts) is controlled by the fourth parameter of the [enqueue function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/). If it is empty, the current WP version is added.

In the link you provide the version is stripped from url after it has been generated. This is not the preferred way to go, since you first do something and then try to undo it. Better not do it at all.

Rather you should set the version of your stylesheet while enqueueing, because in this way you keep track of the versions. Even more correct, when it comes to the main stylesheet `style.css`, you should set the version number in the header of that file and retrieve the version automatically like this:

```
$theme_data = wp_get_theme();
wp_register_style('wpse160190-main-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', '', $theme_data['version'], 'all');
```

This way of working will also eliminate all caching problems.